# What are the prerequisites on the host for running an NFS server in a container?

Tags: linux, nfs, containers

I want to run an NFS server in a privileged Docker container.

A simple “modprobe nfs” on the host is not sufficient according to my tests – starting an NFS server in the container says “Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no support in current kernel”.  The modprobe itself worked, however, as I can see “nfs” afterwards in /proc/modules on the host.

Then, I installed the (Ubuntu) package `nfs-kernel-server` on the host, and now, the NFS server in the container starts successfully.  However, I wonder whether a full-fledged NFS server on the host truly is necessary.

So, what are the minimum prerequisites on the host for that?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you can't start kernel nfsd process inside a container. If you want to use container to export file system, than you need to run a user space nfs server like [nfs-ganesha](https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha/wiki), [nfs4j](https://github.com/dCache/nfs4j) or similar.

Comment: Well, I did it.  ;-)  It really works.

Recently, I found out that there is also a kernel module “nfsd”.  Maybe modprobing this is enough …  I can't test myself because I would have to reinstall my whole server for this.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, and if you was able to run kernel nfsd in container, then post an answer yourself.